# Copying same file to multiple locations / drives with progress bar

Tags: vb.net, system.io.file

I am trying to make a vb.net appliaction designed to copy one file to multiple locations at the same time. But I can't figure out how to stop the `System.IO.IOException` I am receiving because multiple threads are trying to access the file. Here is my current code:

```
Dim parts As String() = targ.Split(New Char() {"\"c})
Dim filename As String = parts(parts.Count - 1) 'target folder name
Dim dir_path As String = "" 'directory without target folder name
Dim FolderList As New List(Of String)
Dim copied As Integer = 0<

For f As Integer = 0 To parts.Count - 2
    dir_path += parts(f) + "\"
Next

Dim counter As Integer = IO.Directory.GetFiles(targ, "*.*", IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length 'counts the number of files
newitm.SubItems(4).Text = "Copied (0/" + counter.ToString + ")" 'displays the amount of copied files
FolderList.Add(targ) 'Set first folder

Do While True
    Dim FoldersInsideDirectory As New List(Of String)
    If FolderList.Count = 0 Then
        Exit Do 'If there is no folder to copy Exit Do
    Else
        For l As Integer = 0 To FolderList.Count - 1
            Dim fileSystemInfo As System.IO.FileSystemInfo

            Dim sourceDirectoryInfo As New System.IO.DirectoryInfo(FolderList(l))

            Dim dest As String = FolderList(l).Replace(dir_path, "")
            If (Not System.IO.Directory.Exists(des + "\" + dest)) Then 'create subFolder inside directory
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(des + "\" + dest)
            End If

            For Each fileSystemInfo In sourceDirectoryInfo.GetFileSystemInfos
                Dim destinationFileName As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(des + "\" + dest, fileSystemInfo.Name)
                If TypeOf fileSystemInfo Is System.IO.FileInfo Then
                    Dim streamRead As New System.IO.FileStream(fileSystemInfo.FullName, System.IO.FileMode.Open)
                    Dim streamWrite As New System.IO.FileStream(des + "\" + dest + "\" + fileSystemInfo.Name, IO.FileMode.Create, IO.FileAccess.Write, IO.FileShare.None)
                    Dim lngLen As Long = streamRead.Length - 1
                    newitm.SubItems(3).Text = "Copy bytes : (0/" + (lngLen * 100).ToString + ")"
                    Dim byteBuffer(1048576) As Byte   'our stream buffer
                    Dim intBytesRead As Integer    'number of bytes read
                    While streamRead.Position < lngLen    'keep streaming until EOF
                        newitm.SubItems(3).Text = "Copy bytes : (" + CInt(streamRead.Position).ToString + "/" + (lngLen * 100).ToString + ")"
                        intBytesRead = (streamRead.Read(byteBuffer, 0, 1048576))
                        streamWrite.Write(byteBuffer, 0, intBytesRead)
                        streamRead.Flush()
                    End While
                    'Clean up 
                    streamWrite.Flush()
                    streamWrite.Close()
                    streamRead.Close()

                    copied += 1
                    newitm.SubItems(4).Text = "Copied (" + copied.ToString + "/" + counter.ToString + ")"
                Else
                    FoldersInsideDirectory.Add(fileSystemInfo.FullName)
                End If
            Next
        Next
        FolderList.Clear()
        FolderList = FoldersInsideDirectory
    End If
    MsgBox("Done")
Loop
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify [**`FileShare.Read`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileshare(v=vs.110).aspx) in the [`FileStream`'s constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5h0z48dh(v=vs.110).aspx):

> **Read**
>
> Allows subsequent opening of the file for reading. If this flag is not specified, any request to open the file for reading (***by this process or another process***) will fail until the file is closed.

```
Dim streamRead As New System.IO.FileStream(fileSystemInfo.FullName, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read, System.IO.FileShare.Read)
```

Comment: Thanks Visual Vincent!

Comment: @ThomasButcher : No problem! Glad I could help, and welcome to Stack Overflow!